# Oscommerce Mail does not send for concatenated string

Tags: php, oscommerce

hi am new to oscommerce plat form,i have a task i.e once user check the mail means it will send to the user email address and admin email address else it will send mail to admin.the problem is here,once i did the condition means it wont send the mail for concatenate string.
My code is given below:

```
VARIABLE NAME:email_address=tep_db_prepare_input(HTTP_POST_VARS['email']);      

tep_mail(STORE_OWNER,emailaddres."xxyt@somemail.com",EMAIL_SUBJECT,subject,message,name, email_address);

tep_redirect(tep_href_link(FILENAME_CONTACT_US, 'action=success'));
```

here i want send the mail to user also.

Answer (score 0):

HTTP_POST_VARS['email']  needs Register Globals to be on which in most servers these days is off( as its a security threat).

echo HTTP_POST_VARS['email']  and check are you getting some value or not else use $_POST['email']